# Rename [dynamics-crm-365] tag to [dynamics-365]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Essentially, there is no such thing as "Dynamics CRM 365". The product is called "Dynamics 365", so the tag should, IMHO, reflect it.

Can we rename [dynamics-crm-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-365) to [dynamics-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365)?

Answer (score 1):

What we can do is suggest a synonym of [dynamics-crm-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-365) in [dynamics-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365), once its voted & approved, it will auto-merge.

For now I created the [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamics-365/synonyms), we can wait for the above process.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that there is no product called *Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365*, Microsoft is promoting a product called "**[Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/switch-dynamics-crm-online-dynamics-365)**". The latter is a collection of separate *Dynamics 365* applications (Sales, Customer Service, Field Service and Project Automation Service [are the default apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/basics/business-apps-dynamics-365)). This product / collection of apps has replaced the former *Dynamics CRM online* ([which also has its own tag in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-online), by the way).

*Dynamics 365* is the umbrella product name for all of their business solutions, which encompasses *Dynamics for Customer Engagement* (i.e., CRM capabilities), *Dynamics for Financials and Operations* (i.e., ERP capabilities) and industry-specific solutions for retails, real estate, etc.

Therefore, [dynamics-crm-365] is actually not a bad tag because it covers the three elements that are probably important to you as a Stack Overflow user : it's Microsoft, it's their CRM and it's online/cloud-based.

**Instead of removing this tag, I would replace it with either**

- [dynamics-365-crm]
- [dynamics-365-customer-engagement]

In my view, both of these tell you more clearly, that you are looking at CRM capabilities within the Dynamics 365 product family. It would make searching for the right tag easier if all the Dynamics 365 apps follow the same pattern of [dynamics-365-{app_name}], the way that [[dynamics-365-sales]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-sales) and [[dynamics-365-operations]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-operations) already do. "Customer Engagement" would be closer to the Microsoft speak but I think "CRM" is more widely-understood (or we could create both and redirect one to the other).

[dynamics-365] would still be useful as a separate tag for questions that cover the entire Dynamics suite and not specifically CRM.